# In how many ways can you divide a class of 7 students into two smaller classes

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

In how many ways can a class of 7 students be split into two smaller classes ?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I tried the case In which 7 can be written as sum of two +ve integers

Comment: This means that you have to choose a subset from a set of 7 students (those who you want to put in the first of the two classes). Do you know how many subsets has a set with 7 elements?

Comment: If the two smaller classes need to be each nonempty, make sure if using method Crosful suggests that you don't select the empty subset or the whole set of 7 as the first class.

Answer (score 1):

Let a string of $A$s and $B$s represent the arrangement.

For example

$AAABBAB$ represents that first $3$ and $6$th students go to group $A$, and rest go to group $B$

This means that every student has $2$ choices, either $A$ or $B$.

This can be done in $2^7=128$ ways.

But this also counts the ways in which all students go to $A$ or all go in $B$, so we can subtract them

$$128-2=126$$

Edit:
As highlighted in the comments, if group A and group B are not distinct, then the number of ways are

$$\frac{126}{2}=63$$

Comment: But is AAABBAB and BBBAABA the same way of splitting the first three and the sixth into one group and the rest into another?  Or is that two different ways of splitting the first three and the sixth into one group and the rest into another.

Comment: Well If Group A and Group B are distinct then different, if they are not, then We can divide by 2

Answer (score 1):

C(7,1)+C(7,2)+C(7,3)=63 Assuming classes are unnamed groups

And if the classes are distinct, then it will be C(7,1)+C(7,2)+...+C(7,6)=126